# PHP zend left join convert date in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend-framework, join

I've a problem while getting schedules from my datebase

DB:

Schedules

```
ID: 1
start_time : 2014-04-04 08:00:00
and more..
```

The left join

```
 //start is defined as : $start = '2014-04-04'

 public function getEntriesForWebuserByDate($businessId,$userId,$date){

    $select = $this->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false)
          ->from(array('i' => $this->_name), array('*'))
          ->where('i.start_time = "'.$start.'"') //Both should be dates

          $select->where('(b.instance_id = ?)', $businessId);
          return $select->query()->fetchAll();

 }
```

//Note: **The left join works fine I just stripped some stuff out**

The problem is I want to check if `start` is the same as `i.start_time` but one is a date and one is a datetime.

Is there a way to convert i.start_time to a date format in the left join?

//Note:
**This is zend 1! And also it is built in a cms**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting your WHERE clause to the following should do the trick:

```
->where('DATE(i.start_time) = DATE(?)', $start)
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't had the time to test it out